# Help with basic inductor

Tags: current, inductor, inductance

I need some help with this basic inductor.

[image]

If I have the current in that direction and those values of voltage and inductance, what is the value of $$\frac{di}{dt}$$ ?

I know that:
$$V_L=L.\frac{di}{dt}$$

So:
$$ (2-0) = 2.\frac{di}{dt}$$
So:
$$\frac{di}{dt} = 1$$

but that's wrong because the answer is

$$\frac{di}{dt} = -1$$

What is wrong??

Thanks

Comment: I think your second equation is wrong - this equation is normally shown as  V = -L di/dt (*note the negative sign*)

Answer (score 2):

The current direction in the diagram is from lower potential to higher potential but in applying the formula you have assumed the current to be from higher potential to lower. The formula becomes:

$$(0-2) = 2\times\frac{di}{dt}$$

**Apply KVL in the direction of current you are assuming**

In this particular question if you rig the circuit up, current will always from from higher potential to lower (2V-0V), hence it is opposite to the assumed direction and therefore negative.

Comment: But why? I do (2-0) because it's $$V_{end}-V_{start}$$

Comment: But how do you decide what is your "end" and what is your "start". Since this is very subjective we use the words higher potential and lower. The easiest way to do this question is to do $$V_{higher}-V_{lower}$$ which is $$2-0$$ but this also means current is also in the direction of higher to lower potential. Because the current we just assumed goes from higher to lower potential and this is opposite to the given direction. Put a negative sign in front of it (to reverse the direction of current because the question asks you to do so).